# how to get current device Data Activity Android

Tags: android, networking, telephony

In my Android app, in need to know if there is some dataActivity or not... 
I know that there is a enum called TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_NONE.

How Can I get this value??

And (as bonus features ;)) there is some method to get the currently download/upload speed?

Here my code:

```
public static int getDeviceNetwokActivity(Context context){
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    return tm.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE
                    | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY);
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have root permission !

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with this code:

```
/**
 * Function that get the current device netwok activity
 * @param Context context - The context of application
 * @return int - [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
 */
public static int getDeviceNetwokActivity(Context context){
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); // TelehponyManager
    return  manager.getDataActivity();
}
```